# rake db:test:load, undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, cloud9-ide

I want create test database. Development database have following settings:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: c9
  username: <%=ENV['C9_USER']%>
  host: <%=ENV['IP']%>
```

When i run command: **rake db:test:load --trace**, displayed error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:526:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge
```

How solve this issue?

Comment: Why use `development` and why not create a `test` configuration in your database configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add configurations for test env in your database.yml.

Also remember to use different database_name for your test db.

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: c9_test
  username: <%=ENV['C9_USER']%>
  host: <%=ENV['IP']%>
```

And then hit this command

`RAILS_ENV=test rake db:setup`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to run the command with a specific environment passed to it.
So to speak:

`bundle exec rake db:test:load RAILS_ENV="development"`

Comment: i tryed, but same error: rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:526:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge

Comment: Thank you, this definitely fixed my problem 