# rake test prepare: NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, minitest

I always get the following error when I run rake db:test:prepare. what can cause this? rake db:create works fine.

```
 Adam-MacBook-Pro:katy adam$ bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
    rake aborted!
    NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:163:in `purge'
    /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:356:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:362:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

database.yml

```
<%= Rails.env %>:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV['DB_POOL'] || 5 %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USER'] || 'root' %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] || nil %>
  timeout: <%= ENV['DB_TIMEOUT'] || 5000 %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>
  port: <%= ENV['DB_PORT'] || 3306 %>
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] || "website#{Rails.env}" %>
```

Comment: Could you please post the contents of your database.yml file ?

Comment: ok, I have updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try specifying the `RAILS_ENV` when you run the rake command:

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: Thnks a lot brother, but why didn't work without the 'RAILS_ENV="test"', as far as I know, I don't really have to specify that

Comment: Apparently, your `RAILS_ENV` is `nil` for that rake task. You usually don't need to specify `RAILS_ENV` if you already have something like this: `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'` in your `spec_helper.rb` file.

Comment: Because, by default, rails starts in development, not in test.

Answer (score 3):

refer this might be the same issue [rake db:test:load, undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684414/rake-dbtestload-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass/32692498#32692498)

or try this

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:setup
```

Comment: thnks, I ll try this later as well, but the answer on the top solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in a github action when I was attempting to run an initializer that used `Rails.application.credentials`

The reason for the error was because I had forgotten to give the github action workflow my `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`, so the github action couldn't get the credentials to use in the initializer.

Once I [added the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` to the github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65310519/5783745), it worked.