# Github actions and RAILS_MASTER_KEY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, github-actions

I've been trying to set up GitHub-actions with Rails, however I'm facing an issue with the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` (my assumption).

This is the error-message I get in the last step `# Build and run tests`:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
/home/runner/work/my-project/my-project/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/home/runner/work/my-project/my-project/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/runner/work/my-project/my-project/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/runner/work/my-project/my-project/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: key must be 16 bytes
```

`.github/workflows/main.yml`:

```yaml
name: CI
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on:  ubuntu-latest
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres:11
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxxxxx
        ports: ['5432:5432']
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    steps:
      # Download a copy of the code in the repository before running CI tests
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Setup Ruby
      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
        with: 
          ruby-version: 2.6.6

      # NPM install
      - name: NPM install with caching
        uses: bahmutov/npm-install@v1.1.0
        # with:
         # cmd: install

      # Build and run tests
      - name: Build and run tests
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:@localhost:5432/test
          RAILS_ENV: test
          RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
        run: |
          sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
          gem install bundler
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
          bundle exec rails db:prepare
          bundle exec rails test
```

I am inferring that this has to do with my RAILS_MASTER_KEY-variable.

I checked the key which I stored in my project's ENV-variables and it happens to be 32 bytes. I am unsure about how to best proceed and I am hesitant to delete the key, fearing I'll break other parts of the application. Setting an option for the key to be legal with 32 bytes would be much preferable in my book - it's just that I wouldn't know how and where...

Any thoughts on how to solve this issue?

Comment: For debugging GitHub Actions, I've found that using `tmate` to "ssh" into the runner and "poke around" is very useful. I'd try adding tmate as a step before your "Build and run tests" step and then from inside the runner inspect the environment variables, try and run the tests with different commands, etc. https://github.com/marketplace/actions/debugging-with-tmate

Comment: Thank you @CaseyFlynn, for taking the time to reply. I followed your suggestion, using tmate and discovered that the env-variables are never set. I wasn't able to figure out why that ist, however once I disabled the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`-line from the workflow all worked smoothly all of a sudden. I don't know how I feel about that, but it works for now which is okay, I guess.

Comment: No problem, regarding the ENV vars that aren't set, when you added the tmate step before your "Build and run tests" step -- did you remember to include the `env:` in your main.yml? If it's still only set on the following job step it wouldn't be present when you're using tmate to inspect.

Comment: I added them to the `tmate`-step additionaly, hoping they'd get set in there. This didn't seem to have worked though.

Answer (score 13):

@Ruslan Vaeev gives the first part of the answer - add the master key value to a GitHub repo Secret. Next use that secret in your workflow yml file by using `${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}` such as:

```yaml
env:
  RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem and I found a solution by creating credentials for my test environment.

`EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit --environment --test`

You might need to upload your test key file to your repo so credentials file can be decrypted. Just be careful to maintain only test info.

I found the explanation here: https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/10/rails-6-adds-support-for-multi-environment-credentials.html

And I uploaded my configs here: https://tello.io/ruby-rails-github-actions-mysql

Comment: how do you do it on production then?

Comment: EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit credentials:edit --environment production

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't clear. I meant do you upload your production key to the repo as well? As far as I've heard that's bad practice

Comment: Yes it is a bad practice. You need to keep your production key secure. Most of the cloud services provide a way to handle secrets. If you are going to upload your key just be sure that is not public and it safe. I mean no one will read it except you or whoever you decide

Answer (score 4):

You need to add secret to your Github repository. Go to "Settings" tab click 'New secret' and put there content of the file master.key and save with name RAILS_MASTER_KEY. Then you can use it in your CI `.yml` file like `secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY`
[image]